# Attached property attached only on the first user control instance

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, dependency-properties, attached-properties

Following Josh Smith example on mvvm workspaces (customers view), I have a mainwindow and a mainwindowviewmodel which contains an ObservableCollection of "ChatTabViewModel":

```
internal class FriendsListViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    #region bound properties
    private ICollectionView viewfriends;
    private ObservableCollection<ChatTabViewModel> _chatTab; 
    ...
    #endregion
}
```

I have an area dedicated to this collection in the xaml like that :

```
<ContentControl Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Content="{Binding Path=ChatTabs}" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource ChatTabsTemplate}" />
```

And in my resources dictionary:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:ChatTabViewModel}">
    <View:ChatTabView />
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate x:Key="ClosableTabItemTemplate">
    <DockPanel>
      <Button
        Command="{Binding Path=CloseCommand}"
        Content="X"
        Cursor="Hand"
        DockPanel.Dock="Right"
        Focusable="False"
        FontFamily="Courier"
        FontSize="9"
        FontWeight="Bold"
        Margin="0,1,0,0"
        Padding="0"
        VerticalContentAlignment="Bottom"
        Width="16" Height="16"
        />
      <ContentPresenter
        Content="{Binding Path=Caption, Mode=OneWay}"
        VerticalAlignment="Center">
      </ContentPresenter>
    </DockPanel>
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate x:Key="ChatTabsTemplate">
    <TabControl
      IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
      ItemsSource="{Binding}"
      ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ClosableTabItemTemplate}"
      Margin="4"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

On user event I add a new ChattabViewModel in my collection and the view related to it appears in the main window.

But when I tried to add an attached property on a scrollbar in the ChattabView, this property will attach only on the first ChattabViewModel instance, the other tabs won't be bound to the attached property. Here's the ChattabView XAML:

```
 <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Grid.Row="0">
  <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Messages}" View:ItemsControlBehavior.ScrollOnNewItem="True">
  <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <TextBox IsReadOnly="True" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Path=DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" />
    </DataTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>    
</ItemsControl>
</ScrollViewer>
```

and the code of the attached property:

```
namespace GtalkOntre.View
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Util class to scroll down when a new message is added.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>attached property called ScrollOnNewItem that when set to true hooks into the INotifyCollectionChanged events of the itemscontrol items source and upon detecting a new item, scrolls the scrollbar to it.</remarks>
    public class ItemsControlBehavior
    {
        static Dictionary<ItemsControl, Capture> Associations = new Dictionary<ItemsControl, Capture>();

        public static bool GetScrollOnNewItem(DependencyObject obj)
        {
            return (bool)obj.GetValue(ScrollOnNewItemProperty);
        }

        public static void SetScrollOnNewItem(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
        {
            obj.SetValue(ScrollOnNewItemProperty, value);
        }          

        public static DependencyProperty ScrollOnNewItemProperty =
            DependencyProperty .RegisterAttached(
                "ScrollOnNewItem",
                typeof(bool),
                typeof(ItemsControlBehavior),
                new UIPropertyMetadata(false, OnScrollOnNewItemChanged));

        public static void OnScrollOnNewItemChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var mycontrol = d as ItemsControl;
            if (mycontrol == null) return;
            bool newValue = (bool)e.NewValue;
            if (newValue)
            {
                mycontrol.Loaded += MyControl_Loaded;
                mycontrol.Unloaded += MyControl_Unloaded;
            }
            else
            {
                mycontrol.Loaded -= MyControl_Loaded;
                mycontrol.Unloaded -= MyControl_Unloaded;
                if (Associations.ContainsKey(mycontrol))
                    Associations[mycontrol].Dispose();
            }
        }

        static void MyControl_Unloaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var mycontrol = (ItemsControl)sender;
            Associations[mycontrol].Dispose();
            mycontrol.Unloaded -= MyControl_Unloaded;
        }

        static void MyControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var mycontrol = (ItemsControl)sender;
            var incc = mycontrol.Items as INotifyCollectionChanged;
            if (incc == null) return;
            mycontrol.Loaded -= MyControl_Loaded;
            Associations[mycontrol] = new Capture(mycontrol);
        }

        class Capture : IDisposable
        {
            public ItemsControl mycontrol { get; set; }
            public INotifyCollectionChanged incc { get; set; }

            public Capture(ItemsControl mycontrol)
            {
                this.mycontrol = mycontrol;
                incc = mycontrol.ItemsSource as INotifyCollectionChanged;
                incc.CollectionChanged +=incc_CollectionChanged;
            }

            void incc_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
            {                
                if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add)
                {
                    ScrollViewer sv = mycontrol.Parent as ScrollViewer;
                    sv.ScrollToBottom();
                }
            }

            public void Dispose()
            {
                incc.CollectionChanged -= incc_CollectionChanged;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So why is the attached property only bound once, on the first "chattabview" occurence of the chattabviewmodel collection? and therefore, working only on the first chattabviewmodel.
When I close them all, the attached property will unbind itself on the last instance of chattabviewmodel, and when I add a new first chattabviewmodel, the property will bind correctly. So it triggers only on the first instance and last instance of the "chattabviewmodel" collection of mainwindowviewmodel.

After a week of searching, I'm a little desperate now...

So far my hypothesis is : the problem might be related to the way I set the view to my viewmodel in dictionary resources. The view might be shared and the first scrollbar only might react. I tried to add an `x:Shared = false` attribute on the DataTemplate tag but it didn't change anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure there are different instances of your `ChatTabView` being created?

I believe WPF's `TabControl` re-uses the existing template if it's the same instead of creating a new one, and simply replaces the `DataContext` behind it.

So it would only create one copy of your `ChatTabView` and switching tabs is replacing the `DataContext` behind the `ChatTabView` to a different item in the collection.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't shown us `ChatTabsTemplate`, so I can only assume it contains a `TabControl`. If so, that explains the behavior you're seeing. The `TabControl` lazily loads its child tab items, so only the current view will be initialized, and hence have the attached property applied to it. When you switch tabs, however, you should see the same attached property firing. Is that not the case?

As for your hunch, it's not quite right. The `DataTemplate` *is* being shared, but the `DataTemplate` is used to create distinct instances of its contents, which are not being shared.

Comment: Yes, I showed you ChatTabsTemplate in the resources dictionary, maybe you missed it ( <DataTemplate x:Key="ChatTabsTemplate"> <TabControl IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" ItemsSource="{Binding}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ClosableTabItemTemplate}" Margin="4"/> </DataTemplate> ) Ok for the tabcontrol, so I understand it will bind the attached property only once. But no, the attached property fires only for the first opened tab (bound to an instance of chattabviewmodel) and the other following tabs won't have the required behavior :(

Comment: Ok I tried without a tabcontrol, the attached property is bound everytime a new viewmodel is added to the collection and it works perfectly. I think you're right, it's not the way of setting the view to the viewmodel but the way the tabcontrol deals with attached property, binding only once. 
So now, how am I supposed to make attached property work with all tabs in my tabcontrol :/

Comment: @Anna: I think you misunderstand slightly (or maybe I do). When you change tabs the `TabControl` will load the view and your attached property *should* execute as a result. It's just that it isn't executing straight away because the view is lazy-loaded. If necessary (I still don't understand why you care when the attached property executes, as long as it does), you can google techniques for having the `TabControl` always load all its children instead of lazily-loading them.

Comment: I understand because I tried binding the view in a more classic way like so : usercontrol.datacontext = viewmodel and I saw in debug mode how tabcontrol worked.Actually when you change tabs it load the concerned view and this view binds its attached property.But when I use tabcontrol + the way I set the view in resources dictionary, attached property only work on the first tab panel. I checked, when you switch tabs, the other views won't bind to the attach property. There is a real problem in using a tabcontrol and setting the view in dictionary resources. You'll see ifyou try the combination.

Comment: Ok I found the problem. The problem lies in the tabcontrol with this way of binding te view and the viewmodel (dictionary resources like shown). When you bind the view through datatemplate, tabcontrol will load the view only once. 
So the user control is loaded only once, hence the attached property only bound on the first instance. I don't know wheter it's on purpose or if it's kind of a wpf bug.